# Cannot select/focus on input field using mouse after clicking on background image

Tags: html, css

In HTML page we have form with user id and password. We also have a background image. Once te form is opened every thing looks fine where we can select inout field and enter data.
Where as if we click on background image first and then try to select inout field to enter data, it doesnt work.

This is happening in IE8. we dont see this behaviour in IE9 or Firefox
please help.

Comment: sample code would help. 
are you loading the image in ie-8 using any ie specific prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow code

> onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
>   onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"

example usage

```
<input type="password" id="PASSWORD" name="password" value="1234567890" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
```

I created a demo fiddle for you

https://jsfiddle.net/1zhdLb55/